# c++ OpenSSL, writing a public key in to a file and reading it from same file does not return correct key

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, pem

I have generated an 256 bytes RSA keypair and I am now trying to write the public key into a PEM file. I am using this code:

```
    // Put the public key inside a pem file
    ofstream file("temppubkey.pem");
    file.close();
    FILE * pemFile = fopen("temppubkey.pem", "w");
    PEM_write_PUBKEY(pemFile, servTempPubKey);
    fclose(pemFile);

    // Retreive key from pem file as a test
    FILE * pem = fopen("temppubkey.pem", "r");
    EVP_PKEY * key = EVP_PKEY_new();
    PEM_read_PUBKEY(pem, &key, NULL, NULL);
    fclose(pem);

    // TEST
    cout << "Pub key:\n";
    BIO_dump_fp(stdout, (const char *) servTempPubKey, tempKeySize);
    cout << "test key:\n";
    BIO_dump_fp(stdout, (const char *) key, tempKeySize);
```

The result I get is usually good for 16 to 32 bytes but I always end up with a different key that I had to start with. Does anyone has any hints on what I am doing wrong here ?

**EDIT**

Here is the file written

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
> MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmHKT/jXk5CwCVheWcWE2
> DrIHml4EsO/IQ5/sDdbrzakryB4YLmu+z90ShE5sYKixHq2oDrjnDbrTL2RYJSrC
> xQmUOztztFXqvh6yWaKlA0la/ehsCQSW8o2OONu84d9Pr3ZgQz4gTdjIeKqF96qm
> hhyLTrVA5qQD0aUgJRTxSbnESQBBvipdNFzGLT/I0kMK3lCbDfANDuhNL8iX8jp8
> KNd6KqrOf3FfzYOII0uIvwVO0OCSm4rXCtIK2euskmCOEVYQZEbWgnzVf/Uos/9J
> bIEDKFks9pcia7uAhlPA/2CZjClQjHde/PcCFq7hRKwn4okoiM5zB9wl688uL/iX
> LQIDAQAB
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

It seems relatively correct from my experience pem files usually look like this.

Comment: are there any binary chars being written?

Comment: Are you writing and reading on the same system, with the same kind of newlines in text-files?

Comment: And what is that `ofstream file("temppubkey.pem"); file.close();` for? If the file doesn't exist, then `fopen` will create it. And if the file *do* exist, then the `fopen` will truncate its old contents.

Comment: Have you tried reading the file into a char* buffer and checking what is read matches what is written?  Doing this should tell you if the problem is in `PEM_read_PUBKEY()` or else where?

Comment: So, I am running this program on local, the code is written in the same cpp file. Since it is a rsa key there are probably binary characters written but I have tried using rb and wb modes result is the same.

Comment: I didn't know that fopen did create file if not existent I am fixing this rn thanks. I'll try to run more tests using char *

Comment: My guess is that the data in the files are correct and the same, but the data in the `EVP_PKEY` structures differ. The `EVP_PKEY` structure is not a string, it can contain context-dependent (and non-text) data that differs between the two instances you attempt to print, and you see it as a false positive for differences in the actual key data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BIO_dump_fp` dumps raw binary bytes from a structure into the file.

Doing this kind of comparison, this way, only works if `EVP_PKEY` points to a trivial type, with no padding.

OpenSSL's documentation makes no guarantees, whatsoever, what `EVP_PKEY`'s underlying object is. In fact, the definition of its contents is completely hidden from OpenSSL's public header files. Here's the verbatim definition of `EVP_PKEY` taken from OpenSSL's `types.h` header file:

```
typedef struct evp_pkey_st EVP_PKEY;
```

The End. No definition of what `evp_pkey_st` is, anywhere. It'll remain an unsolveable mystery, forever.

It's considered to be private information, not even accessible from the public header files. You cannot make any assumption, whatsoever, what it's pointing to. It is an opaque handle, a pointer to some object whose allocation and deallocation is managed by OpenSSL, and you have no direct access to it, whatsoever.

It is unclear where the shown code obtains `tempKeySize` from, or what it means, but it is unlikely to be the correct size of the underlying structure, of what the pointer is pointing to. OpenSSL does not make this information available, either.

In short, dumping some arbitrary number of bytes from wherever a particular `EVP_PKEY` points to will not accomplish anything useful, and is likely to be undefined behavior, anyway.

Comment: ok thank you for your answer, tempKeySize is the number of bytes of the generated key.

Comment: And so to clarify, there is no actual way to be sure we are reading the right key when doing this kind of things?

Comment: If you have a `std::vector` with a million bytes, writing a million bytes starting with this `std::vector`'s address will be similarly useless, for exactly the same reasons. Although `EVP_PKEY`'s definition is not in the public header files, openssl's source code is freely available, and you can look in there and see exactly what this pointer is pointing to. It is not going to be the key itself.

Comment: So I used this key to encrypt/decrypt and it seems that it is working. Thank you for your help, it was in fact a false positive error.